# Using autofilter on excel sheet in Progress 4GL

Tags: excel, vba, openedge, progress-4gl

I have some issue about Autofilter a range of cells on an Excel sheet.

the part of the code:
vchWorkSheet:Range(XLS_col(1) + STRING(2) + ":" + XLS_col(vi_x) + STRING(2)):Autofilter.

where:
XLS_col(1) - **the actual column (for example: "A")**,
vchWorkSheet - **the actual worksheet**,
Range(XLS_col(1) + STRING(2) + ":" + XLS_col(vi_x) + STRING(2)) - **the range of cells (for example: "A2:BB2")**

I've got an error message when building app:
"Wrong number of parameters. Component method Autofilter called with < 3 parameters."

Actually I would like to use only **VisibleDropDown** parameter, nothing to filter in default.

[**Error message here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbWHD.png)

Any idea?

I've tried to add some parameters (for example: vchWorksheet:Range("A2:BB2"):Autofilter:VisibleDropDown = TRUE., or: vchWorksheet:Range("A2:BB2"):Autofilter(,,,,,TRUE).), but i don't know the syntax of Autofilter arguments.

[I would like to display filter option on the range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVbz2.png)

Comment: Posting a small example of running code that produces the error would make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Welcome Szabó! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to use **vchWorksheet:Range("A2:BB2"):Autofilter(?,?,?).** and it solved my problem, so **I just used 3 null parameter** (:Autofilter(?,?,?)) and now the filters are displayed on the range.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I usually do:

```
    chWorksheet:Range("A1:W" + STRING(nTotalRows)):SELECT.
    chWorksheet:Range("A1:W" + STRING(nTotalRows)):AutoFilter("1",,).
```